# Deserialize Json string which includes nested objects using unity3D utility

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to use this code to serialize an object in unity3D based on this Json string:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Cache-Control": "max-stale=0", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 30 Dec 2019 13:08:47 GMT", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "origin": "194.126.25.28, 194.126.25.28", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

I have faced the following problems:

1. Lists with unique Types wont be recognized in the output.
2. Lists will be printed out with square brackets instead of curly brackets.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net;

public class Test01 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string JsonString = wc.DownloadString("http://httpbin.org/get");
        print(JsonString);
        JsonArgs Args = new JsonArgs();

        //Get The objects from Json String
        Args = JsonUtility.FromJson<JsonArgs>(JsonString);

        //serialising Json again to print it to the console
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(Args);                
        print(json);
    }

    public class JsonArgs {
        //private static Headers HD = new Headers();
        public List<string> args = new List<string>();        
        public List<headers> headers = new List<headers>();
        public string origin;
        public string url;
    }

    public class headers {
        public string Accept;
        public string Accept_Encoding;
        public string Accept_Language;
        public string Cache_Control;
        public string Host;
        public string If_Modified_Since;
        public string Upgrade_Insecure_Requests;
        public string User_Agent;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Beause neither `headers` nor `args` are type of list. You should change JsonArgs class according to JSON. Or you can change JSON if you can

Comment: in JSON {} is not a list. It's an object, not a list or array. Lists are represented as arrays with square brackets `[]` instead of curly brackets. Anything in JSON that has curly braces `{}` is an object and needs an equivalent class to deserialize into.

Answer (score 0):

Because neither `header` nor `args` are type of `List`. You need to change `JsonArgs` as following:

```
public class JsonArgs 
{
    //Removed List of string and create args class
    public args args;

    //Removed List of headers
    public headers headers;
    public string origin;
    public string url;
}

public class headers
{
    [JsonProperty("Accept")]
    public string Accept;

    [JsonProperty("Accept-Encoding")]
    public string Accept_Encoding;

    [JsonProperty("Accept-Language")]
    public string Accept_Language;

    [JsonProperty("Cache-Control")]
    public string Cache_Control;

    [JsonProperty("Host")]
    public string Host;

    [JsonProperty("If-Modified-Since")]
    public string If_Modified_Since;

    [JsonProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests")]
    public string Upgrade_Insecure_Requests;

    [JsonProperty("User-Agent")]
    public string User_Agent;
} 

public class args
{

}
```

1. Removed `List<string> headers` to `headers`
2. Create `args` class instead of `List<string> args`. In your Json string `args` equals `{}` that means object without any property!?. So that from this Json it is hard to define properties of `args` class. But it works as well for null object.
3. Added `JsonProperty` attribute to each properties of `header` class so that properties match with json.

Comment: Hi, Thanks !. This was the case actually !. I have to turn them into objects. I have also used the newronsoft.Json library instead of the unity json utility. the utility doesnt show fields of the multi fields class headers in my case.The only problem left is that not all the fields in the header class recieve value.

Comment: {
  "args": {},
  "origin": "194.126.31.18, 194.126.31.18",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": null,
    "Accept_Encoding": null,
    "Accept_Language": null,
    "Cache_Control": null,
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "If_Modified_Since": null,
    "Upgrade_Insecure_Requests": null,
    "User_Agent": null
  }
} as you see only the host field has a value. the other ones are also strings but they have null value.

Comment: I have updated answer. Added `JsonProperty` attribute to the properties of `header` class. Now it has to work

Comment: The output of using Json properties is almost the same as using normal properties. some fields are still recieving null value.

Comment: I have tested this code it is working. Please make sure that you names of `JsonProperty` are matching with the  JSON. For example: `Upgrade_Insecure_Requests` property has `[JsonProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests")]` since `-` character is not valid for property name in c# so that we have to change `-` to `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesnt look right. Your code should like below:

```
public class JsonArgs {

    public string args;        
    public string headers;
    public string origin;
    public string url;
}
```

To handle null values, need to add the following attribute over the property:

```
[DefaultValue("")]
```

More on DefaultValue:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm

Answer (score 0):

It worked finally. hence I have charackters like "-" for example so I used cscore assembly which has functions that parse any string into Jsone objects.